# Notepad++ regular expression help

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm a total newb with expressions and looking for a quick way to do this. Trying to delete everything in between the && to TAG

```
URL GOTO=http://www.URLHERE.com/&&TXT:Just<SP>Because<SP>I'm<SP>Skinny<SP>Does<SP>NOT<SP>Mean<SP>I<SP>Have<SP>an<SP>Eating<SP>Disorder
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=VALUE:Submit
```

Comment: InRe: close votes. I tend to think of regular expressions as a programming topic even in the context of a simple search and replace function.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
&&.*?\bTAG\b
```

with an empty string. That will do it. It also makes sure that "TAG" is a separate word. You should also turn on multiline mode if the line break in your example is not only for formatting, or use:

```
&&[\s\S]*?\bTAG\b
```